# If, And, Or - Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know how to create a IF, OR, AND function with multiple conditions in excel?

I got the function to work (*only 2 conditions are working, function fails when I try to place additional conditions*) using the following formula;

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2>3,C2>1000,E2="Yes"),AND(B2>3,C2>500,E2="Yes")),
"5","4")
```

I need the function to pass any 1 of 5 possible outputs, they are as follows;

```
if (B2>=3 and C2>1000 and E2="Yes") = "5"

 or

if (B2>=3 and C2>500 and E2="Yes") = "4"

 or

if (B2>=2 and C2>100 and E2="Yes") = "3"

 or

if (B2<=2 and C2>100 and E2="No") = "2"

 or

if (B2<=1 and C2<100 and E2="No") = "1"
```

Cheers,

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have such large formulas, always break it up in small parts.

For example

```
'if (B2>=3 and C2>1000 and E2="Yes") = "5"
=IF(AND(B2>=3,C2>1000,E2="Yes"),5,"")
```

Similarly

```
'if (B2>=3 and C2>500 and E2="Yes") = "4"
=IF(AND(B2>=3,C2>500,E2="Yes"),4,"")

'if (B2>=2 and C2>100 and E2="Yes") = "3"
=IF(AND(B2>=2,C2>100,E2="Yes"),3,"")

'if (B2<=2 and C2>100 and E2="No") = "2"
=IF(AND(B2<=2,C2>100,E2="No"),2,"")

'if (B2<=1 and C2<100 and E2="No") = "1"
=IF(AND(B2<=1,C2<100,E2="No"),1,"")
```

All you have to do now is combine them

`=IF(AND(B2>=3,C2>1000,E2="Yes"),5,IF(AND(B2>=3,C2>500,E2="Yes"),4,IF(AND(B2>=2,C2>100,E2="Yes"),3,IF(AND(B2<=2,C2>100,E2="No"),2,IF(AND(B2<=1,C2<100,E2="No"),1,"")))))`

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that you don't have mutually exclusive logic.  For example, your first three expressions can be simultaneously true if the values in B2, C2, and E2 equal 4, 1001, and Yes, respectively.

If you fix your logic, you should be able to effectively nest your functions.

Good luck!

Comment: See the example I provided.  Is not 4 >= 3?  Is not 1001 >= 1000 AND 500?  Is not "Yes" = "Yes"?  If the answers to these questions is yes, then Josh has a logic problem.

Comment: Check my screenshot and the formula. The `If` formula will always check the first condition and then move to the else part if false. The logic is to keep the `C2>1000` before the `C2>500`

Comment: Sorry, Siddarth.  Looked at the logic laid out below the original formula in the initial post.  This is the logic, upon which my comment was based. Yours looks good